# JSP Catch Errors

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tomcat7

I know this has been answered here before, and it's all over google, but I can't seem to get this to work. What I would like to do is catch 400,403,404,500 etc...

I have a controller called index...

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{

    String page = request.getParameter("p");

    if(page == null || page.equalsIgnoreCase("home"))
    {
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("pages/index.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }
    else
    {
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("pages/error.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);          
    }}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
  doGet(request, response);
}
```

This works fine when someone enters a url like localhost:8080/app/index?p=NOT_A_PAGE but I don't know how to catch errors if someone tries to break the url with something like localhost:8080/app/notMYController?p=home or localhost:8080/app/.

I have seen people here, and on google say something along the lines of "Add the following line to your web.xml file which is located in your WEB-INF folder:"

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/pages/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/pages/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Now I tried this, and if I go to something like "localhost:8080/app/indexs" I still get the normal Apache/Tomcat/7.0.12 404 page.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong, or what I need to do to fix this.
Thanks :)

Comment: Do you, in fact, have a /pages/error.jsp, and if so, is 'pages' in the root jsp directory (by default, this is a sibling of WEB-INF named 'jsp')? If not, it will log something to the extent of "in addition, an error occurred while trying to display the error page for <error code>"

Comment: Yea. In my example above I have other pages, and when the url is like "localhost:8080/app/index?p=NOT_A_PAGE" it loads the error page. Just for the hell of it I created an error.jsp and put it in the root of WebContent and changed the web.xml and that didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: You might try just a static error.html file located in the default place. This rules out any configuration errors around getting the error.jsp to render to html.

Also, play with the nesting levels in web.xml. i.e. You could put the rule at the top level (outside of any of your 'app' context). If you're still stuck tomorrow, I'll check back with a real example to consult, and we can move to chat.